# angular ui-grid dynamic event based css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am currently working on a project making use of the [angular-ui/ui-grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid).  While looking through the css used to make it work (via firebug), I stumbled across something I have never seen before.

[image]

When the window that contains the ui-grid is resized the `max-width:` and `min-width:` all update accordingly ...

Where is the css from `events #4` being referenced?

I know that CSS can be referenced from an `external file`, or within `<style>` tags, or `Inline` within a html tag ... but `events #4` doesn't seem to fit any of those descriptions ... so how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its dynamically set as inline style by some angular-ui-grid directive called `ui-grid-style` .

You can search their tutorial grids and you will find something like

```
<style class="ng-binding" ui-grid-style="">
        .grid1442752024758 {
        /* Styles for the grid */
    }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-row, .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-cell, .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-cell .ui-grid-vertical-bar {
    height: 30px;
    }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-row:last-child .ui-grid-cell {
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    }
    /*
    .ui-grid[dir=rtl] .ui-grid-viewport {
    padding-left: px;
    }
    */
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-coluiGrid-0007 { min-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; } .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-coluiGrid-0008 { min-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; } .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-coluiGrid-0009 { min-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-canvas { width: 483px; height: 3000px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header-canvas { width: 500px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header-canvas { height: inherit; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-viewport { width: 500px; height: 168px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-header-viewport { width: 500px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-footer-canvas { width: 500px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-render-container-body .ui-grid-footer-viewport { width: 500px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-footer-aggregates-row { height: 30px; } .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-footer-info { height: 30px; }
    .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-coluiGrid-0007 { min-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; } .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-coluiGrid-0008 { min-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; } .grid1442752024758 .ui-grid-coluiGrid-0009 { min-width: 161px; max-width: 161px; }
</style>
```

[Link to their sorting tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting)